# inputRadioButton - When options attribute contains HTML code

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I would like to use the `@inputRadioGroup` helper (found [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.3/scala/index.html#views.html.helper.inputRadioGroup%24)) in my form template:

```
@inputRadioGroup(
          contactForm("gender"),·
          options = options("M"->"Male","F"->"Female"))
```

Well, everything is ok. But I would like to use `icon/image` instead of `text`. Something like that (with twitter bootstrap css) :

```
@inputRadioGroup(
          contactForm("gender"),·
          options = options("M"->"<i class="icon-user"></i>","F"->"<i class="icon-user"></i>"))
```

Well, in this case, the html code generated is :

```
<label for="gender_M">
&amp;lt;i class=&amp;quot;icon-user&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/i&amp;gt;
</label>
```

The icon html is escaped. No icon is displayed. How can I develop my idea with this helper ?

Note: I tried to use `Html()` method but I got the same issue. The following Scala line code :

```
options("M"->Html("<i class=\"icon-user\"></i>").text)
```

generates the following HTML code :

```
<label for="gender_M">&lt;i class=&quot;icon-user&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt;</label>
```

and the rendering in the browser is :

```
<i class="icon-info-sign"></i>
```

No icon is displayed 'cause the html escaping... Anyone has an idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Override the default field helper, by creating, for example, an `inputRadioButton.scala.html` file in `views.utils` package with below content (modify as necessary):

```
@(field: play.api.data.Field, options: Seq[(String,String)], args: (Symbol,Any)*)(implicit handler: helper.FieldConstructor, lang: play.api.i18n.Lang)

@helper.input(field, args:_*) { (id, name, value, htmlArgs) =>
  <span class="buttonset" id="@id">
    @options.map { v =>
      <input type="radio" id="@(id)_@v._1" name="@name" value="@v._1" @(if(value == Some(v._1)) "checked" else "") @toHtmlArgs(htmlArgs)>
      <label for="@(id)_@v._1">@Html(v._2)</label>
    }
  </span>
}
```

and then when you want to display in your field templates:

```
@import helper._
@import views.utils.inputRadioButton
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to apply a class to the generated label tag, you're out of luck. The code that creates the radioButtonGroup is a scala template itself -- it looks like this:

```
@input(field, args:_*) { (id, name, value, htmlArgs) =>
  <span class="buttonset" id="@id">
    @options.map { v =>
      <input type="radio" id="@(id)_@v._1" name="@name" value="@v._1" @(if(value == Some(v._1)) "checked" else "") @toHtmlArgs(htmlArgs)>
      <label for="@(id)_@v._1">@v._2</label>
    }
  </span>
}
```

As you can see, the label tag is populated with the option label, which is a string that is going to be escaped. You may be able to set the background image with a CSS rule that has a selector something like:

```
span.buttonset#fieldId label:
```

Alternatively, you could create the HTML by hand, or write your own helper according to the [docs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaFormHelpers).